# Why method reference doesn't work with this?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, type-inference, method-reference

I have a method look like this.

```java
static <R> R applyOthers(Some some, Function<List<Other>, R> function) {
    List<Other> others = ...;
    return function.appply(others);
}
```

Now when I try this,

```java
withSome(some -> {
   List<Other> others1 = applyOthers(some, v -> v); // works
   List<Other> others2 = applyOthers(some, Function::identity); // doesn't
});
```

An error, I get.

```
incompatible types: unexpected static method <T>identity() found in unbound lookup
  where T is a type variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>identity()
```

Why `::identity` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function<Object, Object> f1 = v1 -> v1;
Supplier<Object> s1 = Function::identity;
Supplier<Object> s2 = () -> Function.identity();
```

See this piece of code, i guess you just misused the method reference here. When we say `SomeObject::method`, this method reference should match with some functional interface. In the above example, `Function::identity` is kind of supplier instance not `java.util.function.Function` instance.

Comment: That's it, mate! It must be `Function.identity()` not `Function::identity`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't we say that Function::identity is supplier of Function like -

`Supplier<Function<?,?>> a =  Function::identity;`

and that's why its not working ?
If we replace '?' with correct type a.get() works.